# Dynamic IP address

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, dynamic-ip

When a server (nginx, apache) is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0), what happens when one of the interfaces goes down or is modified (perhaps changes the IP address), will the server still be accessible if one has set up a dynamic dns? Does it have to be restarted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the webserver listens on all hosts there is no need to restart it when changes in interfaces / IPs occur.